# Bitwise operation producing unexpected output

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a=0x11;
    printf("\n %d",a);
    int b=10;
    int c=(a&b);
    printf("\t %d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

The o/p of this program is

> 17    0

But I expected the program to operate on bits such that it results in

> 17    16

Why the output is 0?

Comment: What is `o/p`? Output?

Comment: did you mean `int b=0x10;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In binary notation `0x11` is

```
0001 0001
```

while `10` is

```
0000 1010
```

As you can easily see, these values have no common `1` bits. For this reason, the result of bitwise-and operation between these values is `0`. Why did you expect it to produce `16`?

Comment: I think you meant 'bitwise-and', but you're obviously right otherwise:)

Comment: Thank you .while doing bitwise operation compiler always converts any type of no into binary .Am I right sir ??This was my concern

Comment: @Debashish Saha" "Converts to binary" is a wrong way of thinking about it. Bitwise operations *shall* work *as if* they operate on binary representation of the number. How compiler achieves that is its own internal business. Maybe it will "convert to binary", maybe not. (Maybe everything is already in binary.) Most of the time the compiler will simply use a CPU instruction that implements the same bitwise operation. How that CPU instruction works internally - "no one knows". From the language point of view it is magic.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, `b` is having a decimal value 10, not a *hexadecimal* 10. Change

```
 int b=10;
```

to

```
 int b=0x10;
```